# Android drawable animation speed control

Tags: android, animation, drawable

I have several images in an animation.xml

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:oneshot="false" >
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/anim1"
    android:duration="200" />
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/anim2"
    android:duration="400"/>
<item
    android:drawable="@drawable/anim3"
    android:duration="400"/>
```

and so on... and in my MainActivity have

```
ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.view);
view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.view_animation);
AnimationDrawable animation = (AnimationDrawable) view.getBackground();
animation.start();
```

Is it possible to keep this form I mean android:duration="200" for first image and then android:duration="400" for the rests images and let the user select the speed of animation through a spinner???